# VBA Access insert all columns from dataset into access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im copying data from SQL SP (which returns a table) into an Access Table.
Im using CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT Into..."
Its all working fine, but is there a way to just insert all of the columns from the Recordset into the table? At the moment Im typing out each column name, but I have a lot of columns. 
Thanks

Comment: If the columns in the table are of the same type and in the same order as the columns in the source select it should work.  Best way to test is just try it.

Comment: Albert showed you how to do it in his [answer to your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21924523/2144390).

Answer (score 0):

If the column names in the SQL Server table match the column names in Access, yes, it's easy to do.
If column names differ, but you are willing to design a query and name the fields, it is also easy.

```
StrSQL = "Select * from MyTable;"
rsIN.Open ..... strSQL
rsOUT.Open .... Table Name
Do While not rsIN.EOF
    rsOUT.AddNew
    for each fld in rsIN.Fields
        rsOUT.field(fld.name) = rsIN.Field(fld.name)
    Next fld
    rsOUT.Update
    rsIN.MoveNext
Loop
rsIN.Close...... etc, etc,
```